# Why is a BOM being added to an rtf file?

Tags: windows, ms-word, rtf, byte-order-mark

I have a program that runs under Windows and produces a .rtf file ready for Word. Many customers use it successfully. However one user cannot use it because the file appears corrupt when opened in Word, it has what looks like control characters in it. When he sent me the file it had a BOM at the start which was the problem. Also the file appears in an email attachment as "filename.rtf.txt"
1. Any ideas on what is causing the BOM to be added, is it something on his system or his email client?
2. Is there anyway to make Word accept files with a BOM at the start?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: He used Notepad, probably to try to "fix" the file.  That's how it got the .txt extension.  And da BOM.  You'll have to get a better diagnostic, "doesn't open" can't be the same as "appears corrupt".

Comment: Thanks, sorry "doesn't open" was wrong - I have edited the original. The problem is that the user is not very technical and getting details from him is difficult. I was asking in case anyone had come across anything similar. When I tried opening a .rtf file in Notepad and saving it, it didn't append ".txt" to the filename.

Comment: What if the  "no technical user" try Save as... text file(.txt) ?

Comment: user2120666 - that is possible - it doesn't explain the BOM though